# How to flatten a map inside a list?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of `maps`, each map showing the same key attributes `type` and `value`.

Question: how can I use java streams to flatten this into a `Map<String, List>>`?

```
List<Map<String, Object>> source = List.of(
    Map.of("type", "first_type", "value", "1"),
    Map.of("type", "first_type", "value", "2"),
    Map.of("type", "second_type", "value", "3")
);

Goal:
Map<String, List<Object>> goal = Map.of(
    "first_type", List.of("1", "2"),
    "second_type", List.of("3")
);
```

It's probably similar to the following, but how can I group the nested map values by their type?

```
 source.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Comment: why do you expect the output to be still consisting of a `List<Object>` when you have integers there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to grouping by `type` and `Collectors.mapping` to map the `value` and collect as List

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> goal = 
  source.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get("type"),
                  Collectors.mapping(m -> m.get("value"), Collectors.toList())));
```

It's better get result in `Map<Object, List<Object>>` as map key is `Object` to avoid type casting.

Comment: wouldn't compile with the type specified in the question

Comment: @Naman That's why I am not specifying first the result map, though I updated it.

Answer (score 4):

We can achieve this using `Collectors.groupingBy`.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> goal = source.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> (String) e.get("type"),
                Collectors.mapping(e -> e.get("value"), Collectors.toList())));
```

Since the key of the result map is a String, there is an ugly type-casting when extracting the key (`type`).

Answer (score 0):

Just Stream the maps and pull off the type and values.  Then map them to a list.
This uses `groupingBy` to group the values into a target supplier.  But you need to map the value first and then specify the supplier as a `List`.  I also changed `Object` to `String` since that is what you are using.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map =
        source.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m->m.get("type"),
                        Collectors.mapping(m->m.get("value"),
                                Collectors.toList())));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
first_type=[1, 2]
second_type=[3]
```

Of course, you could also do it like this.  This translates to:

- if the ArrayList is there for the specified key `type`, use it.
- otherwise create it.
- In either case it returns that list from the `compute` method where
  the value for the `value` key is added.

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Map<String,String> m : source) {
    map.compute(m.get("type"), (k,v)-> v == null ?
            new ArrayList<>(): v).add(m.get("value"));
}
```